# complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

evaluate the principal value of $i^{i+1}$ and derive a general expression for $\arccos(A)$, where $A$ is a real number $> 1$ and hence find $\arccos (3)$, writing your answer in the same form,

have to use quadratic equation  that uses $\exp(iz)$

Comment: Please let us know where you get stuck instead of (poorly) pasting in a question straight from your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

$i^{i+1}=e^{ln(i)(i+1)}=e^{\pi/2*i(i+1)}=e^{-\pi/2+i \pi/2}=ie^{-\pi/2}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** $i=e^{i\pi/2}$

**Hint 2:** $A=\cos(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$